# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Tags: ajax, laravel

How to pass the route in ajax in laravel without form?

I have a `link` or `route` without form.

```
<div class="row" id="markets">
    @foreach($markets as $market)
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/markets/'.$market->image) }}" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $market->title }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ Str::words($market->body, 10) }}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $market->price }} $</p>
                    <a href="{{ route('cart', $market->id) }}" class="card-text add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>
                    <a href="{{ $market->path() }}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I want to do it with ajax.

```
<a role="button" class="card-text add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var Route = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route("cart", $market->id) }}',
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I see this error

[image: error]

My goal is to make [this](http://tavazostore.com/en/product-list/page/1/pagesize/20) page.

Comment: Simply chnage your route `Route::get...` to `Route::post...` then you can use this with form (post method)

Comment: Then change `Route::post...` to `Route::get...`

Comment: I don't have a form, I have a link

Comment: Can you add your route file? url: '{{ route("cart", ['id' => $market->id]) }}', could be the solution

Comment: web.php    https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiJNz.png

Comment: '{{ route("cart", ['market' => $market->id]) }}'. Make sure that you cleared your route cache with php artisan route:cache

Comment: i see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbcir.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4cwC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing in web.php

```
Route::get('/cart/{market}',"MarketController@cart")->name('cart');
```

to

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/cart/{market}',"MarketController@cart")->name('cart');
```

it seems you are using both `get` and `post` on same route if so then this may be it

EDIT:

try this

```
$('#markets').load('{{ route('cart') }} #markets')
```

What the above function does is it will load the cart route's market id and will replace the current route markets id

also i think it will be better to add

```
<div id="markets">
 <div class="row">
    @foreach($markets as $market)
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/markets/'.$market->image) }}" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ $market->title }}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ Str::words($market->body, 10) }}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ $market->price }} $</p>
                    <a href="{{ route('cart', $market->id) }}" class="card-text add-to-cart">Add to cart</a>
                    <a href="{{ $market->path() }}" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
 </div>
</div>
```

ie to create a div outside of the one you want to replace so the classes wont get mixed as for the for loop it will be only server sided so what you will load is loaded for-looped data

Comment: Well, that's right. But my basket did not change any number.

Comment: are u using if condition for ajex simply like 
if($request->ajax()){
                return "AJAX";
            }

Comment: No, I'm using it.

Comment: well if you want to use ajex it will be better if you use it in starting of function then the function can differentiate that he wants to do some ajex work and run the code inside if or it will run the code for get route but if you want to use an api type then i prefer you make a api controller and use `api.php` in routes so ur url will just add `api/carts/id` at the end this is one thing and other is..

Comment: do you want to change the no in cart when user clicks on add to cart without reload ??

Comment: Yes , I want to change the no in cart when user clicks on add to cart without reload.

Comment: this will do i guess

Comment: I followed step by step like this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-add-to-cart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228108/discussion-between-mahmoud-khosravi-and-rohit-mahajan).